# Identifying the joint distribution from some values of $t \cdot X$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $X, Y$ are $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued RVs.  We already know that $X$ and $Y$ are equidistributed iff $t \cdot X=^d t\cdot Y$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  For which $S$ is it also true that $X$ and $Y$ are equidistributed iff $t \cdot X=^d t\cdot Y$ for all $t \in S$?

Since the set of $t$ for which one has $t \cdot X=^d t\cdot Y$ is closed under scalar multiplication and limits (thanks to studying the characteristic function) we have that any $S$ for which $\mathbb{R}S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ works.  Is there a characterization?  Particularly, I am interested in the case $n=2$ with $S$ being all 2-vectors of the form $(1, k^{1/2})$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  But if a general characterization is available that is interesting to me too.

Comment: I am aware of a theorem of Muntz's which identifies the distribution from only a relatively sparse subset of values, but it is a 1-variable thing, and for Laplace transforms.  I wonder if the 1-variable restriction can be removed by considering the multivariate Laplace transform to arise from an iteration of single variable laplace transforms n times, with the first n-1 times instead outputting measures.

Comment: Please replace every occurrence of "$t\cdot X=t\cdot Y$" by "the distributions of $t\cdot X$ and $t\cdot Y$ coincide".

Comment: This reminds me of a CT scan. CT scans are computed using Radon transforms. I strongly suspect this has been considered extensively in that literature, since there are practical consequences, namely how many images are necessary to create a unique reconstruction of a patient's broken skull or whatever.